# Java caching system with spring

Tags: java, spring, caching, jcs

I already have a system which uses spring's caching abstraction + EhCache Implementation for caching solution. But now, I need to switch EhCache for other solution that gives me distributed features. I found JCS ( java Caching System ) suitable for my problem. However, I haven't managed to find a way to use spring caching abstraction with JCS. Does anyone of you know how if it's possible to use spring caching abstraction with JCS? If so, how do I do it?

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
    net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();

    DiskStoreConfiguration store = new DiskStoreConfiguration();
    store.setPath(
            diskDirectory);
    config.addDiskStore(store);
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
    cacheConfiguration.setName("disk");
    cacheConfiguration.maxEntriesLocalHeap(1);
    cacheConfiguration.setTimeToLiveSeconds(Integer.parseInt(cacheTime));
    cacheConfiguration.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");


    cacheConfiguration.maxBytesLocalDisk(Long.parseLong(diskSize), MemoryUnit.GIGABYTES);
    PersistenceConfiguration perCache = new PersistenceConfiguration();
    perCache.strategy(Strategy.LOCALTEMPSWAP);

    cacheConfiguration.addPersistence(perCache);
    config.addCache(cacheConfiguration);



    return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
}
```

My goal is to find a CacheManager class that works like the one above, and Therefore, be able to use the anottations @cacheble, @key and etc.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered **Infinispan**? It provides distributed features and it has a good spring integration. It also supports JSR 107 api.

An example extracted from the official site:

```
/**
 * This example shows how to configure Spring's {@link CacheManager} with 
  Infinispan implementation.
 */
public class SpringAnnotationConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    public static class ApplicationConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean springCache() {
            return new SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        }

        @Bean
        public CachePlayground playground() {
            return new CachePlayground();
        }
    }

    public static class CachePlayground {

        @Autowired
        private CacheManager cacheManager;

        public void add(String key, String value) {
            cacheManager.getCache("default").put(key, value);
        }

        public String getContent(String key) {
            return cacheManager.getCache("default").get(key).get().toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

        CachePlayground cachePlayground = applicationContext.getBean(CachePlayground.class);

        cachePlayground.add("Infinispan", "Is cool!");
        System.out.println(cachePlayground.getContent("Infinispan"));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. that's exactly what I needed.